# error in editing resolv.conf

Tags: updates

With root access I edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` to add  `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.
saving the file give me

```
"/etc/resolv.conf" E166: Can't open linked file for writing
```

Do you have a idea?
I want to edit `resolv.conf` because apt-get update is not working.

**EDIT**
I am using 18.04 LTS OS.

```
Err:1 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ir.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ir.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease    
  Could not resolve 'ir.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease       
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
Reading package lists... Done       
W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ir.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ir.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ir.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ppa.launchpad.net'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: executing `ls -al` in `/etc` shows me: `resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`. Have you tried editing the linked file (as sudo) directly at `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
`?

Answer (score 0):

I reset the system and login graphically. I don't know why but it resolved the problem. I did not edit the `resolve.conf` anymore.